# Можно ли измерить время выполнения скрипта внутри Docker?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

У меня есть образ Docker, который выполняет **python** код (имя файла передается через флаг **--env**):

```
FROM python
ARG FILENAME_ARG
ENV FILENAME = $FILENAME_ARG
CMD python temp/${FILENAME}
```

Можно ли как-то измерить время выполнения именно кода, а не всего контейнера?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CMD bash -c "time python temp/${FILENAME}"
```

Команда time есть в интерпретаторе bash, который присутствует для образа на основе GNU/Linux.

Выведет в консоль:

```
$ docker build -t so1367738 .
 ...
$ docker run so1367738
 ... Вывод сомого скрипта ...

real    0m0.061s
user    0m0.051s
sys     0m0.010s
```

Современная time встроенна в язык bash и не принимает аргументов. Формат времени устанавливается через переменную окружения. Например, `TIMEFORMAT='%3R'` или в Вашем случае `ENV TIMEFORMAT='%0R'`

Для примера в консоли(не докер)

```
$ export TIMEFORMAT='%3R'
$ time sleep 10
10,003
```

Для образов на WindowsServerCore можно обернуть в powershell https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-command?view=powershell-7.2 - в нем я не силен.

Comment: По моему, очень профессионально. я бы сделал второй докер, в который по REST скрипт стучится "до" и "после" выполнения скрипта. А тут - одна команда, и готово! (правда, я еще не пробовал)

Comment: @S.H. проверенно - работает. Простые вещи предпочитаю делать простыми инструментами, да и в апи докера не углублялся - не было необходимости пока.

Comment: @eri, спасибо, все прекрасно работает

Comment: @eri кстати, а как вывести только real в секундах?

Comment: @S1riyS добавил в ответ

Comment: @eri, перед строчкой CMD bash -c "time python temp/${FILENAME}.py" я добавил CMD export TIMEFORMAT='%3R', но время по прежнему выводится в обычном формате

Comment: @S1riyS `ENV TIMEFORMAT='%0R'`, а  не `CMD export` - экспорт не работает в докере потому как каждая строчка исполняется отдельно.